# Split a data frame column based on a comma

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame with the following structure, titled "final_proj_data"

```
ID          County              Population     Year  
<dbl>       <chr>               <dbl>          <dbl>    
1003    Baldwin County, Alabama 169162         2006     
1015    Calhoun County, Alabama 112903         2006     
1043    Cullman County, Alabama 80187          2006     
1049    DeKalb County, Alabama  68014          2006
```

I am trying to split the column County into two different columns, County and State, and remove the comma.

I tried a number of permutations of the separate() function but I keep getting back this error:

> Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a 
>       character vector

I've tried (among others)

```
  final_proj_data %>% 
separate(final_proj_data$County, c("State", "County"), sep = ",", remove = TRUE)
    final_proj_data %>% 
separate(data = final_proj_data, col = County,
 into = c("State", "County"), sep = ",")
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, or why the "col =" keeps throwing this error. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `final_proj_data %>% separate(County, into = c("County", "State"), sep = ",")`

Comment: The problem with your code is that you're using `$` which is generally not suitable for use with data chained with the `dplyr` pipe` You therefore should replace `separate(final_proj_data$County,.....)` with just `separate(County,....)`.

Comment: @RonakShah, thanks! That worked! Sorry the question was kind of basic but I am new to R and chaining is not something I've used much in other programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and base R:

```
library(dplyr)
 final_proj_data %>% 
 mutate(State=unlist(lapply(strsplit(County,", "),function(x) x[2])),
       County=gsub(",.*","",County))
    ID         County Population Year   State
1 1003 Baldwin County     169162 2006 Alabama
2 1015 Calhoun County     112903 2006 Alabama
3 1043 Cullman County      80187 2006 Alabama
4 1049  DeKalb County      68014 2006 Alabama
```

**Original**:

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`(Just seen that @Ronak Shah commented the same above):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
final_proj_data %>% 
   separate(County,c("County","State"),sep=",")
    ID         County    State Population Year
1 1003 Baldwin County  Alabama     169162 2006
2 1015 Calhoun County  Alabama     112903 2006
3 1043 Cullman County  Alabama      80187 2006
4 1049  DeKalb County  Alabama      68014 2006
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `sub` here for a base R option:

```
County <- sub(",.*$", "", final_proj_data$County)
State <- sub("^.*,\\s*", "", final_proj_data$County)
final_proj_data$County <- County
final_proj_data$State <- State
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this in `base R` using `read.csv`

```
final_proj_data[c("County", "State")] <- read.csv(text = final_proj_data$County, 
              header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)
final_proj_data
#    ID         County Population Year   State
#1 1003 Baldwin County     169162 2006 Alabama
#2 1015 Calhoun County     112903 2006 Alabama
#3 1043 Cullman County      80187 2006 Alabama
#4 1049  DeKalb County      68014 2006 Alabama
```

#### data

```
final_proj_data <- structure(list(ID = c(1003L, 1015L, 1043L, 1049L), 
   County = c("Baldwin County, Alabama", 
"Calhoun County, Alabama", "Cullman County, Alabama", "DeKalb County, Alabama"
), Population = c(169162L, 112903L, 80187L, 68014L), Year = c(2006L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2006L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strsplit` in base R.

```
cbind(d, `colnames<-`(do.call(rbind, strsplit(d$County, ", ")), c("County", "State")))[-2]
#     ID Population Year         County   State
# 1 1003     169162 2006 Baldwin County Alabama
# 2 1015     112903 2006 Calhoun County Alabama
# 3 1043      80187 2006 Cullman County Alabama
# 4 1049      68014 2006  DeKalb County Alabama
```

*Note:* Use `strsplit(as.character(d$County), ", ")` if `County` is a factor column.

***Data***

```
d <- structure(list(ID = c("1003", "1015", "1043", "1049"), County = c("Baldwin County, Alabama", 
"Calhoun County, Alabama", "Cullman County, Alabama", "DeKalb County, Alabama"
), Population = c("169162", "112903", "80187", "68014"), Year = c("2006", 
"2006", "2006", "2006")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```